# Ubuntu 20.04 wont boot and I need to fix grub

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 server, and it is installed on 4 hard drives using Raid 10. I installed Ubuntu onto the RAID 10 from the getgo, so each hard drive has a section with the boot-up files.

The setup has worked fine for almost 2 year, and this friday I upgraded (as I do often) by using apt-upgrade to install the newest PHP updates etc., and after I restarted the server it won't load anything, and it just stops with the BIOS logo. If I put in a bootable USB-drive it will work, so nothing wrong with the server itself. Something happened to the boot files. I cant even get to the Grub menu.

I have tried to start up with a Live cd and using Boot repair, but that does not work. I can see all of the drives listed, but thats it. I can also seem them listed in Bios.

So, I am thinking to install Ubuntu on a new single harddrive, and perhaps use that installation to connect to the RAID 10 setup so I can retrieve my files.

This is where I need help. The best would be to fix my current setup, but retrieving my files is the most important to me, and I cant move the RAID 10 setup to another computer and read the files.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated, and what would YOU have done?

---

I am using MDADM Raid 10.

I am not using RAID for backup, but mostly for speed. Of course, if one drive fails, it is good to be able to replace it.

But, I am wondering how easy (or difficult) it will be to assemble the drives with MDADM raid if I install Ubuntu on a new disk.

I have backup of the files, but they are more than 1 week old, and if I can get my latest files, then I will be happy.

**Update:** I am booting from MDADM Raid 10, and one of the disks had been removed even if its health is 100%, so  I used another Ubuntu installation to add the disk back to the array, and when I restarted the machine it booed again.

Comment: I have full install on external SSD, and would use that to boot. I now have stopped using flash drives as they are slow ( and I still have several larger flash drives with different versions & data). My external SSD is almost as fast as an internal SSD drive. But I do not have server install, just desktop. RAID is not considered as backup, so do you have good backups?

Comment: Does your server machine have a hardware RAID controller and you disabled it and configured software RAID instead?

Comment: There is no indication of RAID failure? I would still be tempted to fix grub. Can you provide `/etc/fstab` and `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid`? I'm keen to know if you're using a separate `/boot` partition. Is it a UEFI system?